# SQL Temporal Tables Include Current State

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2016, data-warehouse, temporal-tables

We want to implement temporal tables in SQL Server 2016. We are creating a data warehouse and developing type 2 slowly changing dimension tables.

We noticed that history tables only include history. We want to create a table which has history *and* current state (with EndDate being Null or 12/31/9999).
Is there any way to perform this, without creating a view to UNION current and history tables?

If I have to go with a UNION view, did SQL Server optimize internals, so there would not be any performance issue, for 50 million rows? I have to give the datawarehouse to customers and executive management, there should not be any noticeable difference.

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.Department
    (
        DeptID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        DeptName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        ManagerID INT NULL,
        ParentDeptID INT NULL,
        SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
          CONSTRAINT DF_Department_SysStartTime DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME() NOT NULL,
        SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
          CONSTRAINT DF_Department_SysEndTime 
        DEFAULT CONVERT( DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59' ) NOT NULL,
        PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
    )
    WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.DepartmentHistory));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporal tables support the `FOR SYSTEM_TIME` syntax. One of its options effectively does the UNION for you. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017#how-do-i-query-temporal-data):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL;
```

> ALL   Returns the union of rows that belong to the current and the history table.